# What is the right way of iterating over django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am dynamically creating a form like so;

```
def partial_order_item_form(item):
    """dynamic form limiting optional_items to their items"""
    class PartialOrderItemform(forms.Form):
        quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'class':'quantity','maxlength':'5'}))
        option = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=OptionalItems.objects.filter(item=item),widget= forms.RadioSelect())

    return PartialOrderItemform
```

with that,i can render the options in the template like so and it works perfectly;

```
{% for item in form.option %}
 {{ item }}
{%endfor%}
```

but this `{{ item.price }}` does not work. I need a brief explanation on why its not working and a way to go about it.

I have looked around but failed to find similar questions (i must not be searching the right way ), links are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the field queryset if you want to iterate. Use manage.py shell to instantiate a form and introspect. Why not use form.as_XXX?

Comment: am not using form.as_xxx because i want to be able to access more attributes of the option like its price. form.as_xxx only returns the item.

Comment: form.fields["option"].queryset